# Click Event on a HyperLink in a webpart

Tags: web-part, development, custom

Trying to add a click event to a hyperlink, but couldn't find any way except people using this code of line with some javascript,

```
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    //link.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return handleHyperLinkClick(this)");
    link.Click ??
    AddControl(link);
    AddControl(new LiteralControl(string.Format("</p>")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LinkButton instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Or simple use JQuery event binding on whatever link for the UnObtrusive way of doing it.

See here for attaching it http://api.jquery.com/click/